# Fatal exception when I run my application (retrofit)?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, retrofit

So I have an application which pulls information from an API using retrofit as the library. I thought I had it all working but whenever I run the application I get a null pointer exception and the app crashes and I'm unsure why:

The interface that builds retrofit:

```
    public interface FriendsAPI {

    static final String URL = "https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/";

    @GET("https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/iau/LocalUsers.php")
    Call<User> getFriends();

    class Factory {

        private static FriendsAPI service;
        public static FriendsAPI getInstance() {
            if (service == null) {
                Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .baseUrl(URL)
                        .build();
                return service;

            } else {
                return service;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Stores the JSON array into a list:

```
public class FriendsInfo {

    @SerializedName("Users")
    @Expose
    private List<User> Users = new ArrayList<User>();

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The Users
     */
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return Users;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param Users
     *     The Users
     */
    public void setUsers(List<User> Users) {
        this.Users = Users;
    }
}
```

Finally where I'm calling it (and the code that triggers the fatal exception, although I don't know why):

```
 public void populateFriends(){

        FriendsAPI.Factory.getInstance().getFriends().enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
                String tempLat = response.body().getLat();
                String tempLon = response.body().getLon();
                tLat = Double.parseDouble(tempLat);
                tLon = Double.parseDouble(tempLon);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("Failed :(",t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

I think I've included all the relevant code but if there is anything missing I can post it here. I also have a more complete version of the project on Github.

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Are you sure that `tempLat` & `tempLon` are not `null`? You should add a `null` check before parsing it to double.

Comment: Hmm I'll add a check now but I'm not sure why they're returning null if that's the case, shouldn't they be returning values from the API?

Comment: It might be returning the response but then you'll have to check that. Also, you'll have to make sure that you are parsing the received response properly.

Comment: Hmm ok thanks I'll have a look and see if I can fix it

Comment: Please paste the logcat output containing the crash.

Comment: @ShadabAnsari Here is the output: http://pastebin.com/ZNRY5chx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not written anything to `service`  inside `getInstance()`. Hence it is always `null`. You need to assign the `retrofit.create()` object to `service`.

```
public static FriendsAPI getInstance() {
            if (service == null) {
                Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .baseUrl(URL)
                        .build();
               service = retrofit.create(FriendsAPI.class); //Add this line
                return service;

            } else {
                return service;
            }
        }
    }

            } else {
                return service;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you I missed that! I've updated the code, when I run it now though I get a slightly different error http://pastebin.com/5CNV68wv

Comment: That is  because you are passing null value in  java.lang.Double.doubleValue() in onMapReady callback.

Comment: Hmmm ok I'm going to have to track down the source of that it shouldn't be a null value. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If service is null you return null, change it like this

```
class Factory {
   private static MyApiEndpointInterface service;

       if (service == null) {
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .baseUrl(URL)
                    .build();
            service=retrofit.create(FriendsApi.class);
            return service;

       } else {
            return service;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll change that now


Edit: I get a warning about incompatible types when I write that?

Comment: You have a problem with your service instance, change the type to MyApiEndpointInterface and you instance it like service=retrofit.create(FriendsApi.class); I editend my post, take a look.